# Vim :Explore, don't edit file when pressing <Enter>

Tags: vim

in Vim, I type :Explore to open the vim browser.
When I press  on a directory, I enter the directory as desired.
When I press  on a file, I start editing that file. I would like to do something else.
So basically I would like to map  to 'enter directory' for directories, and something custom for files.

Answer (score 1):

The *netrw* plugin allows opening of file in the current window, (vertical) splits, and a remote Vim instance. The closest built-in functionality to what you want is *customized browsing with a special handler*, which is triggered with the plugin's <kbd>x</kbd> mapping; cp. [`:help netrw-x`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-x).

You can customize via an external command, or a Vimscript function that you define ([`:help netrw_filehandler`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw_filehandler)). In this, you can do "something else", with all the power of Vim to implement it.

As for the distinction between directories and files, this mostly falls flat due to the different keys used. If you need to distinguish in your custom function, the [`isdirectory()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#isdirectory%28%29) function is there to help.

#### alternative

The [NERD tree plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) offers an alternative to netrw, and also offers a similar extension, either via custom mappings, or a menu. As it's mostly a drop-in replacement for netrw (but with additional functionality), it might be worth to check it out before investing too much in customizing netrw.